# Data Grid View VB.net 2013 , How many rows and which are visible in window?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a datagridview control with 10 rows on my form window.

Now lets suppose the size of the datagridview in the form can only display 5 rows to user and user has to use vertical scroll bar to see the other 5 rows.

now my question is :

Is there any way to know which 5 rows are currently visible to the user according to the position of scroll bar.

Actually in my program currently i am updating the all the rows value one by one of that datagridview table continuously.

Now i want to only update the rows that are visible in the window. so how can i know what rows are visible according to scroll bar position.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just found that there is a DataGridView.DisplayedRowCount Method which can give the count of how many rows are visible in the window.   So now one problem is solved now next thing how to know which is the top or bottom row of that visible window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataGridView` control exposes a `VerticalScrollingOffset` property which can be used to determine how far the view is scrolled. If you know the height of each row in the `DataGridView` in pixels, you can then calculate which rows of the table are currently visible and refresh them.

The height of each row can be determined through the `DataGridViewRow` property `Height`. This defaults to the font height, plus 9 pixels - if you're using the same font size in all rows this should be consistent.

**EDIT:** Further digging through the documentation shows that each `DataGridViewRow` exposes a `Displayed` property that returns **true** when the row is visible on the user's screen. Checking that would be much easier!

[MSDN on DataGridViewRow.Displayed property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.displayed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: can you please also tell how to calculate or get row height.

Comment: @luck Updated it again. Much easier than I originally thought!